# How to allocate more memory to a JAVA program when executed from MATLAB?

Tags: java, multithreading, matlab, memory-management

**Introduction:** I have recently been working on a rather heavy computational JAVA program (ODE Solver and numerical optimization). I have implemented multithread and will soon get access to a rather 'large' server here at the university to test the programs performance. I have created the program as a .jar file but I do not execute this .jar file. Instead I use the MATLAB JVM environment to use the specific classes in JAVA, to execute directly from MATLAB. The reason being that MATLAB has so cool graphics functionality.

**Description of current execution method:** As described the program is executed directly from MATLAB in following manner:

```
clear all
javaaddpath('..\binJava\MyFile.jar')
import functionality.*;
import domain.*;
```

I start importing the file and hereafter loads the packages in the file (where all my code lies).
From here I simply execute:

```
myClass.execute(myInput);
```

**Question:** *How can I change the ram allocation in the java program from MATLAB?*

Since implementing multithread have and will speed up the computational job I would like to ensure that the RAM does not become a bottleneck once I borrow the server. I would like to make the RAM adjustment *very user friendly* such that I can adjust the ram usage directly from matlab to the java code in order to take advantage of the server power.

**Litteratur survery:** 
In short the litterateur I where able to find focus mainly on options of increasing RAM on the uses of either Eclipse (or different enviroments) or when executing the .jar file from the terminal (which is not the case for me).

**Final remark:** I am not even certain that memory allocation will become an issue once I execute from the server. It may be that the hardware itself will control this. I have no idea - please share with me your ideas and comments. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `-Xmx` command line option to allocate more memory.

There seems to be a good answer to this here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92813

> 1. Create java.opts file:
>
> Create a text file named java.opts in the $MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH directory. $MATLABROOT is the MATLAB root directory and $ARCH is your system architecture, which you find by typing at the MATLAB Command Prompt:

Then further down:

> Users can override these values by setting them manually in a java.opts file. For example, including the following line in a java.opts file sets the Max Heap Size value to 256 MB:
>
> For JVM of 1.2.2 and later, place the following in your java.opts file:
>
> -Xmx256m

Comment: This is perfect - apparently MATLAB allows one to adjust that in preferences as well Preferences->MATLAB->General->'Java Heap Memory Preferences'. Thanks Tim!